# I can't find specific UUIDs at bluetooth.com

Tags: bluetooth, gatt, bluetooth-gatt

I am using Core Bluetooth in iOS using Swift and Xcode with a Teslasz Fitness Tracker HR, which has the peripheral name "ID115Plus HR". This peripheral has a service with UUID 0AF0. However, that UUID is not present in the list of services on the [bluetooth.com web site for GATT Services](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/services/). I even searched the entire bluetooth.com web site for the UUID. It didn't find anything. Neither are the characteristic UUIDs -- 0AF1, 0AF2, 0AF6, 0AF7

Comment: It is custom service and custom characteristics.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko Do you think Teslasz will give me the specifications?

Comment: Who knows. But take a look on this: https://github.com/Freeyourgadget/Gadgetbridge/pull/1153/files/fe9ec9b88adb454150bf7bd6c1a8309ba0a69ae3

Answer (score 1):

I've been doing some work on my end with some of these generic and No-name Fitness Wearables. You have to subscribe to the characteristics before you can start getting data.